# nginx multiple subdomains

Tags: nginx

Есть множество сайтов на одном домене. На данный момент все ручками прописано - каждый сайт в своем конфиге. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы поддомен автоматически подставлялся на основе существующих папок в `/var/www/html/sitename`. Если возможно, то есть ли какие нибудь примеры или инструкции, тк не могу найти нигде

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для случая `sub1.site.ru` => `/var/www/html/sub1.site.ru`

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name         *.site.ru;
  root                /var/www/html/$host;
}
```

Для случая `sub1.site.ru` => `/var/www/html/sub1`

```
server {
  listen              80;
  server_name         *.site.ru;
  root                /var/www/html/$subdomain;

  set $subdomain "";
  if ($host ~* ^([a-z0-9-]+)\.site\.ru$) {
    set $subdomain $1;
  }
}
```

Для произвольной связки `sub1.site.ru` => `/var/www/html/sub1-dir` с использованием `map`:

```
map $host $sub_root_dir {
  sub1.site.ru sub1-dir;
  sub2.site.ru sub2-dir;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name         *.site.ru;
  root                /var/www/html/$sub_root_dir;
}
```